# How do I change the font size of a twisties/grouped item on SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, jquery

I found a great thread teaching how to change the font of the items of a list on SharePoint and it worked great for each item, but I would like to change the size of the twisties or group header of the list too.

Is there an easy way to do this?

This is the code I have:

```
    <style>

    .ms-vb2, .ms-vb {font-size: 12pt;}

    TH .ms-vb {font-size: 12pt; }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try this CSS for class `ms-gb`

```
<style>
.ms-gb {
font-size: 20pt ! important; }
</style>
```

**[output]**

[image]

Comment: Dear @Blake Great news, Should you set this as answer and upvote it  if it worked and helped you :) you can also check tour links to can know how to do this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour